# jQuery and Session PHP

Tags: php, jquery, session

I have a site developed in php and jQuery.
I want when I click a radiobutton to make some control into my array $_SESSION.
If I make a cycle for each key of the session the first time the cycle ignore many value.
This is my script jQuery

```
$('#livraison').click(function(){
  <?php
  foreach( $_SESSION as $key => $value){
  ?>
  alert("here <?php echo($key); ?>");
  <?php
  }
  ?>
});
```

If I print the array I have this:

```
array(15) { ["order_by"]=> string(13) "titolo_fr ASC" ["iva_1899"]=> string(5) "19,60" ["id_"]=> NULL ["qta_"]=> NULL ["iva_"]=> NULL ["iva_1891"]=> string(5) "19,60" ["iva_2191"]=> string(5) "19,60" ["id_2191"]=> string(4) "2191" ["qta_2191"]=> string(1) "4" ["idcarrello_2191"]=> string(4) "2191" ["nomecarrello_2191"]=> string(23) "Irpinia Rosato Ros'Aura" ["qtacarrello_2191"]=> string(1) "4" ["totalecarrello_2191"]=> string(5) "34,00" ["ivacarrello_2191"]=> string(5) "19,60" ["familles_2191"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

And the cycle the first time block after qta_2191.
But if I reload the same page and click into the radiobutton the cycle go until the end.
The printed array is the same.
Why the first time the cycle foreach block at the middle of the array? 
I don't understand because I print well the array, and if i reload the page is all ok.
Why?

Comment: When are you filling your session variable?

Comment: You shouldn't use alert. use console.log for testing purposes since many browser restrict usage of alert(). often you are not able to open many alerts continuously.

Comment: I set my session variable when I load  page but the event jquery is on a click and not when I load the page.. @asifsid88

Comment: I have use console.log.. same problem @mr.VVoo

Comment: I mean you are sending your values from JS to php using AJAX to set the session and on the same page trying to access that?? In this case the page refresh is necessary

Comment: I don't send via ajax the value because I have thought that when I load the page I set the session value, after a click on a radio I can take this value

Comment: Why don't you want to use cookies?

Comment: Because in this case I need session is a cart of product cookies isn't the good way

Comment: you are setting session values using PHP code or js code?